# React rendered html does not match console.log

Tags: reactjs

I have a pretty basic react component that displays a random value. The random value is computed when the component is first displayed. This random value is stored in a react state and it is never updated afterward:

```
function getInitialValue()
{
  const initialValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  console.log(`initial value is ${initialValue}`);
  return initialValue;
}

function MyRandom() {
  const [randomValue, setRandomValue] = React.useState<number>(getInitialValue);  
  console.log(`Rendering a random value of ${randomValue}`);
  return <p>Random value: {randomValue}</p>
}
```

Then, my react app simply instantiates this component:

```
function App() {
  
  return <MyRandom/>;
}
```

When I start this with `yarn start`, I see the following in the html: "Random value: 33"

But then, when I look in the chrome console, I see this:

```
initial value is 91
Rendering a random value of 91
```

This puzzles me. How can the log say that the random number is 91 while the value seen in the browser is 33. If I reload the web page, I still see that the random number in the logs does not match the random number being displayed.

Anybody understands what is going on?

Comment: You have `React.useState<number>(getInitialValue);` but that should be `getInitialValue()`, right?

Comment: the useState param can be a function that returns a number I'm pretty sure. So invoke or not, same same.

Comment: This is interesting. `const [randomValue, setRandomValue] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {setRandomValue(getInitialValue())},[]);` solves the issue. Still really curious to know what is happening though.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if the function got invoked but I'd never seen that before.

Comment: I tried to repro this in a sandbox but it's rendering the same number as it's logging (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-sp2x8).  Can you provide a sandbox demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I have added the code to reproduce the issue here: https://github.com/mabead/react-random-number-bug. I can reproduce it on both windows and WSL2 using node v14.18.1 and v16.13.0.

Answer (score 2):

The example provided (https://github.com/mabead/react-random-number-bug) is using react 17. If the example is downgraded to react 16.7, we can see a different behavior: the component is instantiated twice and the logs of the second instance matches what is seen in the html:

[image]

It looks like this change of behavior between 16.7 and 17 is caused by the following: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/18547